# --enable-static vs --disable-shared

Tags: libraries

I understand the importance of shared vs static libraries. However, several programs I have come across recommend compiling with

```
--enable-static
```

while other recommend

```
--disable-shared
```

Are these the same thing? And if not, what is the difference?

If possible, please give an example of when to use one as opposed to the other.

Comment: That really depends on the library! There's no "yes" or "no" answer to this.

Comment: It is unclear to me that these are doing different things. Can you please elaborate on what one of these flags is doing that the other is not?

Comment: What about the documentation is **specifically** unclear? That's nothing about the language, nor the compiler.

Comment: Oh. I thought this was a compiler-level directive. My mistake

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the common case that these are switches to a "configure" script generated by [Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/) and [Libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/), then they officially mean closely-related, but different, things.  `--enable-static` means *do* build static libraries; `--disable-shared` means *don't* build shared libraries.

If you want to be sure to get only static libraries, no matter what, you need to give *both* options.  However, often just `--disable-shared` will have that effect, because think about the possibilities: if the package builds only static libraries by default, then `--disable-shared` is a no-op; if it builds both static and shared libraries by default, then you just have to turn off the shared libraries to get what you want; and if it builds only *shared* libraries by default, then you might think you need both options, but if you just say `--disable-shared`, Libtool will usually notice that it's now being asked to build *nothing*, assume that that couldn't possibly be what you wanted, and flip the `--enable-static` switch for you.

Comment: 1+1 = .. thanks for taking the time to explain in further details. I believe there is a lack of explanations on why 1+1=something in the general 'sphere' and i guess it comes from the many people learning from such a ressource as this (fff-ing great, btw) "heresite" without taking interrest (let alone'deep) as to why/what/when/who/weird, applying any sort of seamingly 'genuine' research method(s). You can only speculate (in my world and without looking like an idiot) on things you kinda/actually/somewhat know... Oh well. I know ONE thing for sure; Not only do i abuse punctuation, im bad at it